# How can I implement two sequential pairs of (MATCH, SET) queries with OpenCypher in Apache AGE?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I'm trying to implement two sequential pairs of (MATCH, SET) as in following code, please note that the example below can be replaced with one (MATCH, SET) pair as the example is just for demonstration purposes, but in my situation two sequential pairs is a must:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
MATCH (a: person {name:'yousef'})  SET a.name = 'yousef222' RETURN n.name MATCH(b:person {name: 'mostafa'}) SET b.name = 'mostafa222' RETURN a.name ,b.name
$$) as (a_name agtype, b_name agtype);
```

when I run the query I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MATCH"
LINE 2: ...name:'hla'})  SET n.name = 'hlaaaa' RETURN n.name MATCH(b:pe...
                                                             ^
```

How can I resolve the issue while maintaining the two sequential pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `WITH...AS` clause like so:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher ('test', $$ MATCH (a: person {name: 'yousef'}) 
SET a.name = 'yousef222' 
WITH a.name 
AS a_name 
MATCH (b: person {name: 'mostafa'}) 
SET b.name = 'mostafa222' 
RETURN a_name, b.name $$) 
AS (a_name agtype, b_name agtype);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to resolve the syntax error you're getting is to split the original into two separate queries with each query containing a MATCH and SET pair. Here's one way to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
    MATCH (a:person {name:'yousef'}) SET a.name = 'yousef222' RETURN a.name
$$) as (a_name agtype);

SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
    MATCH (b:person {name:'mostafa'}) SET b.name = 'mostafa222' RETURN b.name
$$) as (b_name agtype);
```

This example will help you resolve the issue while maintaining two sequential pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The synatax error you encountered was because you used `n.name` and `n` was not defined in the query,
but you can implement two sequential pairs of (MATCH/SET) by modifying your query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
MATCH (a: person {name:'yousef'})
MATCH (b:person {name: 'mostafa'})
SET a.name = 'yousef222', b.name = 'mostafa222'
RETURN a.name, b.name
$$) AS (a_name agtype, b_name agtype);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here issue is with query that you are trying to use MATCH-SET pair in a single pair. You can only have single MATCH clause for single return therefore split your query in two separate cypher.

```
SELECT * FROM cypher ("name_here", $$ MATCH (a:person{name: "your_name"})

 SET  a.name= "name_here" RETURN n.name $$ ) as (a_name agtype)'
```

similar write another one like this